# ssh login - access denied (raspberry resets password)

Tags: ssh, password

When I boot the raspberry and try to login via ssh with username:pi and password:raspberry I only get the "access denied" message as if the password were not correct. I found out that the password is always list after reboot so I have to set the password for pi manually everytime to be able to use ssh login.

I have used chage to check if the password expiration is disabled and it is. Does anyone maybe know why the raspberry always deletes the password for the user pi or at which point the raspberry should set the password automatically?

Comment: The only time I saw this issue was when the Pi was underpowered, the PSU was fine but the low quality USB cable just lost too much power. The SD filesystem corruption surfaced as not being able to ssh in.

Comment: So a higher quality usb cable might help? Just found out the root password gets resetted too after each restart.

Comment: worth a try also use a multimeter to check the voltage as per http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in terminal

```
$ sudo bash 
$ cd /boot
$ mv boot_enable_ssh.rc boot.rc
$ sudo shutdown -h now
```

on restart, this worked for my Pi, should work for you too :)